# MS Access - How to add a name to Group Header

Tags: ms-access, grouping, ms-access-2013

I feel like I'm going crazy looking for a setting to give a Group header a name that will display in an Access report.  So I'm using Office 2013 and I'm making a report that includes a "Category" field.  I want to group the report by these different Categories.  This is easy to do - Group & Sort -> Click Add a Group -> Select the field I want to group by.  BUT I cannot figure out a way to give distinction to these headers that now appear throughout the report.  It's just a bar with no words on it.  Is there anyway to add the name of the Category (name of the field that is used to create the groups) onto the group header?

Please help!

Edit: If it matters, the data is being pulled from a SharePoint list.

Comment: Can you share the SQL you generated that is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Add a textbox bounded to the category field in the group header